How can I use Springer "svmult" latex template in local with Visual Studio Code?
I'm trying to use this template from Overleaf
text
I executed this on Overleaf it worked well.
However, since I upload a lot of images, I prefer to run the Latex code locally.
But even the template sample generated errors like this.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 10) line 3.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 10) line 4.
Initial Win CP for (console input, console output, system): (CP949, CP949, CP949)
I changed them all to CP949
Rc files read:
  latexmkrc
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Apr. 2024. Version 4.85.
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'pdflatex' forced or previously required:
    Reason or flag: 'Initial setup'

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "c:/Users/.../authorsample.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/.../authorsample.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>

! LaTeX Error: File `svmult.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
c:/Users/.../authorsample.tex:14: Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.14 ^^M
        
c:/Users/.../authorsample.tex:14:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on authorsample.log.
Latexmk: Missing input file 'svmult.cls' (or dependence on it) from following:
  ! LaTeX Error: File `svmult.cls' not found.
Latexmk: Sometimes, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
  But normally, you will need to correct the file(s) that caused the
  error, and then rerun latexmk.
  In some cases, it is best to clean out generated files before rerunning
  latexmk after you've corrected the files.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'authorsample.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'authorsample.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'authorsample.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'authorsample.log' and/or above output for details

C:\texlive\2024\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:922: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2024\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf -outdir=c:/Users/... c:/Users/.../authorsample

And I opened log file and they warned me like this
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.7.25)  12 AUG 2024 14:59
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**c:/Users/.../authorsample.tex
(c:/Users/.../authorsample.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>

! LaTeX Error: File `svmult.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
c:/Users/.../authorsample.tex:14: Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.14 ^^M
        
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 20 strings out of 473584
 524 string characters out of 5732363
 1925908 words of memory out of 5000000
 23011 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 19i,0n,29p,145b,17s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
c:/Users/.../authorsample.tex:14:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

I don't know why the svmult package doesn't have a problem on Overleaf, But the log tells me it has some problem. So I changed the package in the 'authorsample.tex' name like this.
\documentclass[graybox]{style/svmult}
And executed the file, but there were other errors like this.
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/.../style/svmult.cls",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "File `article.cls' not found.",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/.../style/svmult.cls",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Emergency stop.\n<read *>",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 227,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 227,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/.../style/svmult.cls",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": " ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on authorsample.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'authorsample.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'authorsample.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'authorsample.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 227,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 227,
    "endColumn": 65536
},{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/.../style/svmult.cls",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "LaTeX: You have requested document class `style/svmult',
               but the document class provides `svmult'.",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 65536
}]

I don't know why they generated message like this.
"File 'article.cls' not found."
So I was suspicious of my texlive 2024, but other tex files ran without any problems.
Still, I reinstalled the program just in case, but the problem remained.
What should I do???

BTW: The first two “Use of uninitialized value …” messages seem to be configuration or similar errors before running PDFLaTeX. You should check the configuration.

The problems with You have requested document class `style/svmult' or ! LaTeX Error: File `svmult.cls' not found. can be avoided using a local installation of the files of the template (classes and packages) → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

I added style files in C:\Users\Admin\texmf by your advice but it doesn't work for me.
Do overleaf setting their cls files automatically??

How can I check the configuration?? I searched about that error I think that error is related with some perl language. But it vanished after I edited 'smvult' to 'styles/svmult'.

C:\Users\Admin is usually wrong unless your user name would be Admin (which is usually not a good idea). Ask TeX Live the correct TEXMF root as explained in the accepted answer. Also note, that you have to use the correct subfolder …/texmf/tex/latex/sv/ or similar, where … is, e.g., the result of kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME.

And about the configuration: Sorry, but I do not know Visual Studio Code. But as an alternative you can try to run pdflatex from a terminal window (e.g. cmd.exe or PowerShell).
